# Python twisted with multiple protocols on one port

Tags: python, twisted

How can i use multiple different protocols on one port with twisted? Or how can i change protocol on the fly after same client actions?

Comment: At a guess, you'd have to create your own protocol that can do these things. "Change the protocol after Something happens" is a very generic requirement so I'm not sure there's an existing solution.

Comment: How are you going to know which protocol to use?

Comment: For example if first user packet is "echo" then we should use EchoProtocol and if user packet is "SMTP" then we should use SMTPProtocol

Comment: You can create a dynamic protocol, see this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502090/twisted-how-can-i-identify-protocol-on-initial-connection-then-delegate-to-app

Comment: First answer is not useful for me, because i'm using protocols from twisted library. Second answer is not working =(

Comment: The first answer (mine) is useful even if you're using protocols from Twisted itself.

Comment: I would go with the server mirror of what @schlenk suggested.  Your protocol factory should create DecisionProtocol instances whose only responsibility will be to esatblish actual proto upon first data batch and then delegate its Protocol inherited methods to actual Protocol used. However you will not always be able to decide between protocols based on first message recieved from client.  Think of Protocols where server is the first to "introduce" himself.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like working (=